# update amazon linux ec2 database server(MONGO DB) is 3.0 and I need to update my database to 3.4 without any data loss

Tags: linux, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mongodb

I have an Amazon Linux instance as a Database server (Mongo DB ), but the version of my existing database server is 3.0 and I need to update my database to 3.4 without any data loss. how can I do this can you please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

In order to upgrade from MongoDB 3.0 to 3.4, you have to first upgrade from the 3.0 to 3.2 release series and then from the 3.2 to 3.4 release series.

If you want to avoid any unexpected problems in the upgrade path I'd recommend you:

- Read about [Compatibility changes in MongoDB 3.2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2-compatibility/) and consider any that may apply to your use case.
- [Take a backup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups) of your existing 3.0 production deployment.
- Restore the backup into a MongoDB 3.0 development/staging environment so you can test the upgrade process.
- Upgrade your driver(s) to a version with [full 3.4 compatibility](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/) (since that is your end goal)
- If you are using any third party admin tools, you should also upgrade those to versions with full 3.4 support.
- Follow the steps in [Upgrade MongoDB to 3.2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2-upgrade/) to upgrade your 3.0 test deployment to the final MongoDB 3.2.22 release.
- Test, test, test!

Once everything appears to be working well:

- Read about [Compatibility changes in MongoDB 3.4](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4-compatibility/) and consider any that may apply to your use case.
- [Take a backup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups) of your upgraded 3.2 test deployment.
- Follow the steps in [Upgrade MongoDB to 3.4](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4/#upgrade-procedures) to upgrade your 3.2 test deployment to the latest MongoDB 3.4.x release.
- Test, test, test!

If you are comfortable with the above steps and have resolved any issues encountered in your test environment, you should be ready for a successful production upgrade.

The actual upgrade process shouldn't take much time, but following the above steps will help you avoid any surprises for your production upgrade.